# AppleScript reading apostrophes as ‚Äô

Tags: file, format, applescript

I am trying to make an application in AppleScript to read a list of songs in a text file and I am able to read the file fine until there is an apostrophe (') in the text.

My text file has the content of

```
Follow Me Down
Money For Nothing
Better When I’m Dancin’
```

And the code is:

```
set theFile to "/path/to/file"
set fileHandle to open for access theFile
set songs to the paragraphs of (read fileHandle)
close access fileHandle
display dialog songs
```

However AppleScript outputs `Can’t make {"Follow Me Down", "Money For Nothing", "Better When I‚Äôm Dancin‚Äô"} into type string.`. I know there is another error which says it cannot type the array into a string, I don't care about that since I just wanted the output of the array, what I do care about is why does an apostrophe make it output "‚Äô" instead.

If anyone could help me to fix the apostrophe changing to the characters "‚Äô", that would be great, also it would be good to know why this happens too.

Comment: Again, it's probably a question of text encoding

Comment: @vadian Where do I put `as class «utf8»`>? Where I put it (after "read fileHandle", "read fileHandle) " or "dialog songs") it says 'Expected end of line, etc. but found “«”'

Comment: after `fileHandle` within the parentheses

Comment: Do you mean (read fileHandle as class «utf8»)? If so I have already tried that.

Comment: @vadian Fixed it. Thanks

Comment: try is without the `open/close for access` lines, just `set songs to paragraphs of (read theFile as class «utf8»)`

Comment: @vadian the `«` needs to be before `class`. The code works better with the file handler though.